# What is the correct configuration using opensearch and magento

Tags: magento2, configuration, search, installation, opensearch

I have a basic setup of Magento & Open search.

I have been following the guide here https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/overview.html?lang=en

In the guide it is recommended to install open search so I did so following this guide:
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/docker/

Under the quick installation section titled "Install the application" in the magento guide, there is an example command:

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=opensearch \
--opensearch-host=os-host.example.com \
--opensearch-port=9200 \
--opensearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
--opensearch-timeout=15
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, I get the error:

```
Could not validate connection to OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster.
```

This is strange because when using `docker ps` I can see three nodes, one for the dashboard and two for search.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                                                                      NAMES
4aaed976caf1   opensearchproject/opensearch:latest              "./opensearch-docker…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp, 9600/tcp, 9650/tcp                                                                     opensearch-node2
8a6e26709a6b   opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest   "./opensearch-dashbo…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, :::5601->5601/tcp                                                                  opensearch-dashboards
31e3e15d8ae0   opensearchproject/opensearch:latest              "./opensearch-docker…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, :::9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9600->9600/tcp, :::9600->9600/tcp, 9650/tcp   opensearch-node1
```

I tried changing the host name to localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, opensearch, opensearch-node1, opensearch-node2, opensearch-cluster and some others but none of them work.

Any ideas on how to point magento to the docker cluster?

Comment: Where did your magento running? on docker or host computer?

Comment: magento is on host machine and open search is on docker

Answer (score 0):

**Please run the below command to run the opensearch**

sudo systemctl enable opensearch

sudo systemctl start opensearch

**Check opensearch port.**

curl -X GET https://localhost:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure

curl -X GET https://localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v -u 'admin:admin' --insecure

Comment: This is not correct as you will see I am using a docker container. opensearch is already running and curl is successful. The question is not about how to start open search but where to point my magento instance to look for the docker container.